# Поклонники stdlib ругаются на мой стиль

Tags: c

Необходимо переоформить внешний вид так - чтобы был понятен смысл функции.

```
#include "stdint.h"

char*  hex_char(char* tail_txt, uintptr_t value)
{
    unsigned int tmp;
    int nc = 0x577F << ((sizeof(nc)-2)*8);
    *tail_txt = 0;
    do{
        do{
            tmp = value & 0x0Fu;
            tmp -= 10;
            tmp -= tmp >> ((sizeof(tmp)*8)-3);//-?:7
            tmp += 10 + 7 + '0';
            *(--tail_txt) = tmp;
            nc <<= 1;
            value >>= 4;
        }while (value );
    }while (nc < 0);
    *(volatile char*)--tail_txt = 'x';
    *(volatile char*)--tail_txt = '0';
    return tail_txt;
};
```

Функция должна корректно работать на 16-32-64битных системах.
https://godbolt.org/z/bnfEbaxa1

На данный момент функция принимает указатель на конец буфера и число без знака способное вместить адрес. Выдаёт указатель на первый символ строки с завершающим нулём. Результат - строка в hex формате. Очень важным условием является то, что 0xF должен быть дополнен до 0x0F, 0x12F -> 0x012F, 0x1234F -> 0x0001234F, 0x12345678F -> 0x000000012345678F. Иначе анализаторы строки сойдут сума.

Вот, нужно переоформить функцию, дописать комментарии, поменять имена переменных, да что угодно. Изменить так чтобы пояснительной записки не требовалось.

Comment: Вот именно об этом я и говорил, тихо поставил минус и ничего не предложил.

Comment: Хотелось бы понять, что вы понимаете под утюгом, его пользователем и т.д. Мне кажется, что даже небольшие комментарии существенно бы облегчили понимание вашего кода кем угодно. А вообще... *"Вопросы ... должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей."*

Comment: Ок, утюг убрал.

Comment: Я могу добавить комментарии к каждой строке кода. Но в таком случае будет трудно понять где находится лишний груз.

Comment: Ну, мне сам принцип указания на хвост и возврата указателя на какое-то промежуточное значение в блоке памяти очень не нравится... Да и как-то уж очень сложно вы все это делаете...

Comment: Спасибо, теперь вижу что ботинки разного цвета (целый день ходил).

Comment: Указатель на хвост массива исключает ошибку в работе функции. https://godbolt.org/z/vxMxMzxTz. char txt[8] - предупреждений нет. (должно быть char txt[20]. Возврат на промежуточное значение в памяти не имеет значения - он всегда указывает на начало строки.

Answer (score 2):

Вам не кажется, что вот так код станет понятнее?

> Хотя сам ваш принцип — передача *конца* и возврат указателя на *средину* блока мне ОЧЕНЬ не нравится...

```
char*  hex_char(char* tail_txt, uintptr_t value)
{
    *tail_txt-- = 0;
    do 
    {
        unsigned char v = value&0xFF;
        *tail_txt-- = "0123456789ABCDEF"[v&0x0F];
        *tail_txt-- = "0123456789ABCDEF"[v>>4];
    } while(value >>= 8);
    *tail_txt-- = 'x';
    *tail_txt = '0';
    return tail_txt;
};
```

Comment: Очень важным условием является то, что 0xF должен быть дополнен до 0x0F, 0x12F -> 0x012F, 0x1234F -> 0x0001234F,
0x12345678F -> 0x000000012345678F. Иначе анализаторы строки сойдут сума.

Comment: @AVI-crakHome Это еще проще... Исправил

Comment: 0x0001234F в сокращённом варианте - аля адрес 24бита. (ok 0x01234F)

Comment: Для cortex m3 GCC сократил  " *tail_txt-- = 'x'; *tail_txt = '0'; " до одной записи, и вылетел с ошибкой. Не выровненный доступ к памяти однако.

Comment: А я тут при чем? :) Я до одной записи не сокращал, и писал все посимвольно. Что до *Указатель на хвост массива исключает ошибку в работе функции* - да ничего он не исключает. Передадите не того размера память, например, и до свидания. Рано как и не мешает возврату указателя на средину блока при неверном размере блока или значении с нулями впереди, типа https://godbolt.org/z/WqPh5v6ra...

Comment: *0x0001234F в сокращённом варианте - аля адрес 24бита. (ok 0x01234F)* Ха! вспомните, о чем я писал в самом первом комментарии, и что вы благополучно проигнорировали: ***Вопросы ... должны включать желаемое поведение***. Вы описали требуемое поведение? Нет. *Результат - строка в hex формате* — не описание, да и мой код формально так и поступает. Не забывайте — при неточном ТЗ результат — ХЗ. Кто ж вам доктор, что вы беретесь решать задачу, условие которой не в состоянии сразу внятно сформулировать? не с того вы начали изучение программирования...

Comment: Я обрезал шапку до однозначной проблемы. Как изменить или дополнить комментариями - это и есть  вопрос.

Comment: Оставив ваше решение? увольте, это из серии задаваемых тут вопросов "как мне переписать на (ассемблере, С, С++) мое решение, чтоб оно проходило по времени" при том, что оно использует алгоритм типа O(n^3) вместо O(n log n) :) В вашем измененном вопросе остается неточно указанным один вопрос — о конкретной длине строки. Я догадываюсь , что вы хотите, но все же укажите точно, чем руководствоваться - длиной ненулевой части или размером `uintptr_t`. И, кстати, "с ума сойдут" только примерно так же хреново написанные анализаторы...

Comment: В сам GCC встроен очень хреново написанный анализатор. Когда он видит 0x12F или 0x1234F в большом количестве - время обработки возрастает в 30 раз. Для того чтобы работало быстро - количество символов должно совпадать с известными GCC типами. Он так работает.

Comment: "Жаль, что мы так и не заслушали начальника транспортного цеха". Т.е. что вы так и не ответили на существенные вопросы о том, что же ***в точности*** должна делать ваша функция. На этом умываю руки, помогать тому, кто не хочет идти навстречу - увольте...